# How can I protect my job from a client publishing it elsewhere?

Tags: business, client-relations, corel-draw, file-format

I am designing a brochure of 1,872 pages for a client. This client is asking me provide him with a copy of the job. I am 100% sure if I provide a copy this job is gone. He will print it elsewhere. This client loves my graphics, but he doesn't want to pay for it. I must definitely provide a copy for him. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to protect the job from him printing it?
2. Is there software I can pass my Corel Draw file through to lock and protect the job, but such that it is still readable?
3. Is there a way I can secure my file so that even when printed it will lose quality or come out blurred?
4. Is there a way I can make it readable, but not printable?

Is there software at all for Corel file security?

Comment: This is a legal question, not a technical. You can protect your work by contacting a lawyer and in no other way.

Comment: @Davor Lawyer @$250/hr < Low res PDF $0. So what happens if he hires a lawyer to protect his files? He then needs to spy and investigate the client for the next 6-24months to make sure he didn't print the files, not sleep at night because of anxiety and then sue the client if he ever prints the files? It doesn't work so well to hire a lawyer when you think about it!

Comment: Make a contract of what you expect.

Comment: Perhaps make the first few pages hi-res to prove that you are able to produce a file in the required format and quality.

Comment: @go-meek - one way or another, you will be giving the client full-res files in the end. Low res pdf is not a solution for this question at all. And no, he doesn't need to do any of that.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing the work *before* getting paid at all? Don't do that. As other's have stated, the solution has nothing to do with technology. It has everything to do with having a legal contract in place before you do the work.

Comment: @go-meek that's not good advice. If you are doing design work for clients, you need a legal contract to protect you. This really has nothing to do with 'policing the file' but rather just making sure you are getting paid for the work one does.

Comment: Also, as an aside, I think it's a stretch to call 1,872 pages a "brochure". That's more like a series of novels. :)

Comment: If you built this for the client under contract, typically the client owns it after you are complete. (ie. they can do whatever they want with it).

Comment: “Starting work without a contract is like putting on a condom after taking a home pregnancy test,“ says Mike.  [F*ck You, Pay Me](https://vimeo.com/22053820) - Video of Mike Monteiro. [Review of the talk](http://www.amramperez.co.uk/blog/2014/4/24/rfcmrk0kbyyynvljzy9898j4r8tabx) with some good "cliff notes". Is there a contract in place? or are you half way done without anything signed?

Comment: @da01 I never said to not have a contract, you don't need a lawyer every time you sign a contract to my knowledge...! Please read my answer again, you're even repeating things I've mentioned (heehee!) And by the way a 1800 page brochure = 900 pages back/front printed booklet... It can be done in one book. SnakeDoc is right again. Again the key is being paid for your work (not just a contract with promises of payment, but real $$$) and not providing high quality final files before last payment!

Comment: @go-meek and what I'm saying is that if one has a contract, then the issue of high-res files should be moot.

Comment: @DA01 Then what if you have a contract? How will you know your files are not being used for printing? Then what if that happens? You sue? Then what if you win? Pay collection agents? Then what if the client is dirt poor? Oh... no money or months of waiting. Is it worth it? We don't know how much that booklet is worth. Again, see my first comment here. even if you have a contract you also need to prove the client did something he shouldn't. Most designers don't have a team working for them and policing everything ;)

Comment: @go-meek those are all questions one should ask before even accepting a job from a client. I'd argue don't work for any clients you feel you need to "police". Life is too short for gigs like that. :)

Comment: Don't work for dishonorable criminals?  (as opposed to non-criminals, and criminals that you feel you can trust to pay you!)

Go to great lengths to defame him and his company if he does commit this crime against you?

In this internet age it's not so hard to thoroughly disgrace someone who deserves it.

Comment: Were you hired to **design** the brochure or to **design and print** it? Why **"must"** you give a copy? A "must" implies a contract. If no contract exists now, have one available for signing at the time you hand anything over.

Answer (score 41):

There's ways to add security features on your PDF that will prevent people from printing, editing or extracting elements from the file. There's also watermarks that can be added. BUT there's also ways to bypass all this, so it's not 100% reliable. I could also easily imagine it must have taken you a lot of work to do this work, and your client could easily invest in finding someone to remove any security you may add to that brochure.

**So the best thing to avoid your file being used for printing is simply to lower its quality and make it an unacceptable quality for printing.**

You can export a PDF from your Corel Draw file and then use Adobe Acrobat Pro to change all the pages to image-only, and to a low screen quality (eg. 90ppi and less.) Even if your client has the idea of going to a print shop or using another designer to work on the files, everybody will tell him/her the same thing; your files are low resolutions :)

Having a contract is nice but that's never a guarantee to get paid. By giving low resolution files to your client and requiring your payments, you keep the control and power over the situation. The client won't have choice to comply. And that's fair too.

---

**Here is a link with instructions how to quickly change all your 1800+ pages into a low resolution PDF with images/JPG only.**

[Create a PDF from illustrator without being able to see the individual objects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/create-a-pdf-from-illustrator-without-being-able-to-see-the-individual-objects/57876#57876)

---

> **One thing for sure: Never give a PDF proof with vector and/or high
>   resolution content that is unprotected and *NEVER EVER* GIVE YOUR
>   EDITABLE FILES!** Proofs should be low resolutions PDF or JPG, not "print-ready" or editable CorelDraw files! You give those files after you got your money. In fact, the editable CorelDraw files should be sold separately at least 3x the price of the project! Normally, designers do not provide editable files unless there's a budget for this.

**One last thing... Please, get paid, get down payments as you begin your projects;** split the full amount of that project in many milestones and wait for your payments before sending proofs or doing any revisions. The way you're telling your issue, it sounds like you haven't received any money at all and did an enormous brochure for that client. I can see why you might be very anxious about all this, a 1800+ pages booklet requires a lot of work!

If the client likes your illustrations but doesn't want to pay for them, remove the illustrations. That's it.

Comment: Giving high-resolution files to a client should be no big deal provided there's a proper contract in place to protect both parties.

Comment: PDF "security" enforcement is literally up to the PDF program implementation - ie. if the client happens to have some other PDF reader installed other than Adobe's, that program might very well completely ignore the "do not print" security settings, etc... (even without your client knowing they are circumventing some restrictions).

Comment: @SnakeDoc Yes and if its a open source PDF viewer then it can not really have this option at all, since the user could disable the check from the source.

Comment: @DA01 A contract doesn't guarantee payment and if you read the question of the OP, he's not dealing with a client who seem to respect this.  A contract is a nice bonus but I wonder if giving your high res wouldn't be seen as being NEGLECTFUL actually. That's like leaving your keys on the dashboard of your car because "you have an alarm system anyway"... Anticipating issues smarter than trusting signature on paper. And I agree with SnakeDoc, that's why removing vectors and flattening the images to lowres is still the safest way to go.

Comment: @go-meek if a designer has to 'outsmart' their clients that don't adhere to contracts, then that designer needs to find much better clients.

Comment: @DA01 Not Da01, don't forget to count the time spent going to court instead of working, the lawyer's hourly rate , transport, accomodation, etc. The concept of negligence is something that can play against you; any business owner has the responsibility to make sure they're not blindly trusting clients and delivering high value goods/services without collecting money. It's idealistic to solve an issue by saying "this isn't a good client"; well maybe it isn't but that offers no solution to the current issue and often the designer realizes this AFTER working for that person.. rarely before!

Comment: @go-meek from what I understand, the OP is about to undertake a project and is worried about not getting paid. They can either try and 'outsmart' this client with technology, or they can take the professional route and make sure there's a legally binding contract in place and/or put some thought into the type of clients they are working for in the first place. I'd argue the latter is the more prudent option when it comes t doing business. No one should do work for clients they don't trust, nor should clients work with designers who don't trust them.

Comment: @DA01 You’re talking about this as if it’s an either-or situation. It is not. **It’s a both-and situation.** There should always be a legal contract—particularly with new clients that you don’t already have a good relationship with—but not handing over all your editable work before seeing a dime of your payment any time the client asks is a sensible precaution that should _accompany_ any contract(s) you make with the client. You cannot always know upfront whether a client is trustworthy, and it’s better to find out he isn’t _without_ having given everything and received nothing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree completely with you. But my point is that all should (and can) be handled with the contract. Things like a down payment before work commences, a detailed list of deliverables and conditions with said deliverables, etc. Certainly don't do all the work and hand over final files *before* a contract is signed and you get paid (partial or in full depending on your contract). If we're talking about designing **two thousand pages** without getting any money up front, then this is a business contract 101 issue...not a technology issue.

Comment: @DA01 You should simply post your answer. It looks like you started with "give high res, trust client and contracts are #1" & now you're saying the same thing we kept saying; it's confusing. I don't even sign contracts (yep), & lost a huge $50 in 10 years of full-time business. Amazingly, simply getting paid in an intelligent way, not giving final files until full payment, & having good communication works perfectly fine. What's cool about not having contracts is that I can freely tell some clients to F*** O** too. So it goes both ways. Of course, that's not recommended for newbie designers.

Comment: Best answer thus far!

Answer (score 17):

Unanswered Question #1: **What is in your current contract?**

What is written down and signed currently? What has he promised in writing? What have you promised in writing?

> "Starting work without a contract is like putting on a condom after taking a home pregnancy test"

[F*ck You, Pay Me](https://vimeo.com/22053820) by Mike Monteiro

FYPM is a WONDERFUL talk about the importance of contracts, and the importance of getting them right. [This review](http://www.amramperez.co.uk/blog/2014/4/24/rfcmrk0kbyyynvljzy9898j4r8tabx) of the talk has some good "cliff notes" that I'll blatantly put here:

- Contracts protect both parties. This means if anything happens on either end it is stipulated in the contract.
- Don’t start work without a contract.
- Don’t blindly accept their terms. If they’re an established company then they have hired a lawyer to write up a contract. It is important to go through the contract with your lawyer and negotiate if you find something you don’t agree with.
- Don’t start work without a contract.
- Anticipate negotiation, but don’t back down on important stuff. Such as:

  - IP transfers on full payment: This is when the work you have done is yours until the client pays you in full. If they were to go ahead and use the work before paying then you are legally allowed to sue them.
  - Termination: This is a fee that the client has to pay you for terminating the contract before completion. This will cover you for the work you have turned down, to be able to work on their problem.
  - Liability: This is when something has gone wrong and you now bare the responsibility for dealing with that problem.
- Don’t start work without a contract.
- Lawyers talk to lawyers. If you are dealing with a client who has a lawyer on the phone, then you must get your lawyer to speak to each other otherwise you may end up agreeing to things you didn’t want to due to nerves.
- Don’t start work without a contract.
- Be specific and confident talking about money. Talking about money is a nerve racking to talk about. I have experienced this when quoting people for work and it really is a hard thing to talk about when asked in person. If you’re trying to convince somebody over how much something costs Monteiro emphasises not to start with ‘mmm’ as this may lose your client. If you know how much something costs then you should tell them and in the case of not knowing then say you don’t know and you will let them know as soon as possible. Monteiro mentions that you should always talk like you know what you’re talking about even when you don’t, because you can always find out later.
- **Don’t start work without a contract.**

Is there a contract in place? or are you half way done without anything signed?

**Give your Client options.**

Provide tiered options. Random example that I would start with:

- for $, you get printed copies provided by me (Provided upon full payment)
- for $$, you get a low quality, highly watermarked PDF (Provided upon full payment)
- for $$$, you get a medium quality, medium watermarked PDF (Provided upon full payment)
- for $$$$, you get a high quality, rarely watermarked PDF (Provided upon full payment)
- for $$$$$, you get the production copy and all rights (Provided upon full payment)

Give him options and let him decide what he wants to pay for. Your time is money and you deserve to be compensated.

Comment: +1 for "Starting work without a contract is like putting on a condom after taking a home pregnancy test"  !

Answer (score 11):

Agreeing with the solution proposed by @go-meek, but perhaps the best way to avoid the issue would be printing the brochure yourself. Tell him that you can only give a printed proof, digital files after receiving the payment. It is fair, he can see the brochure and make annotations in it, you keep the files. Doesn't need to be the highest resolution either, as to avoid him reproducing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

It's not technically possible to have a file that is secured for printing while having the ability to read it. That is because rendering for screen and print is the same thing. Despite this, PDF files have a flag to disable printing; this is more of an annoyance than an actual block.

The best thing you can do is rasterize the graphics to a low-enough resolution to be adequate on screen. Perhaps keeping the images on your server and show them on demand.

Better is to have your client on contract saying he will pay you xxx if he prints it. But bigger yet, why do you have a client that is not paying you anything?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you convert all the text in the file to curves. For that, select all text and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. This would make text uneditable. To check if all texts are converted into curves, go to text statistics and see if there's any font displayed, if not then all texts are converted into curves. Secondly, insert a watermark and export it to PDF in a very low quality so that it would be unclear in printing. Hope that helps.