# Is it possible to break up a PDF in to a grid for security?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I want to break up a pdf into a grid so it can not be copied. I want each page broken up into say 20 rectangles so the image on the page can not be copied when opened?

Comment: You can use something like ImageMagick's "crop" feature to break an image into tiles, but nothing stops someone from reassembling them into an image again.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62262/how-can-i-protect-my-job-from-a-client-publishing-it-elsewhere/62265#62265

Answer (score 1):

If something can be accessed or seen, it can be copied - this applies to both physical and digital works. Your suggested idea will only make it slightly harder.

Comment: yes, but this, combined with a watermark, can make it just that bit too hard for the average computer user.

Comment: No, cutting the image into a grid before putting it into the PDF doesn’t do anything, because you are going to assemble it into one image again before publishing. I can screen capture it out, no problem. And I have yet to meet an “average computer user,” but I bet you mean the people who have never noticed a watermark in their lives.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than go through all that trouble, I would recommend simply creating the PDF with security that prevents copying or printing. That is a readily available solution already at your disposal that would not require the added work of slicing up of your image. Combine that with a watermark layer for added security. Granted, PDF security can be easily broken with the right software, but it's more than sufficient for the average user.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea doesn’t work at all because even if you cut your source image into a grid, you are then going to assemble that image into one image in your page layout app and then export as PDF. If I want to copy that image, all I have to do is do a screen capture of it with any non-Adobe PDF reader, such as the one that is built-into a Mac, iPad, or iPhone. So all you are doing is making work for yourself.

PDF already has built-in security features that prevent printing and editing. If those aren’t enough for you, then don’t publish the image. Make a print of it and put it in a safe.